# Is it safe to use a compressor stored for a year in an unheated shed?

Tags: tools

I had a compressor sit in a shed, not directly exposed to elements but to whatever moisture is in the air (I do live in a high moisture location).

There was virtually no water to drain from the tank when I pulled it out since I did drain it before putting it away often enough.

Can I use it? Is there danger of corrosion?

Comment: *"Can I used it?"* (which is really *"It is safe for me to use it?"*) is unanswerable since it calls for speculation. Now I've heard of, and have firsthand knowledge of, compressors stored undrained for YEARS being used subsequently, and not necessarily lightly/occasionally either. But that is of course no warranty of any similar action being safe in other cases. Edit: just to clarify, I mean safe for the compressor, not for the user; AFAIK the risk of anything dangerous happening with a compressor that has a corroded tank under pressure is small to non-existent.

Comment: Sorry Graphus I might be misunderstanding. Are you saying risk of using a corroded tank compressor not dangerous? Would't the pressure build up to 150lb and then the corroded tank will explode sending metal shards flying?

Comment: Would't the pressure build up to 150lb and then the corroded tank will explode sending metal shards flying?  - Very unlikely, although not impossible.   If the tank is corroded to the point of pressure failure, it will have relatively small areas that fail first, resulting in a small pinhole leaks breaking through.

Comment: _Stored in a shed for one year_ does not seem to be excessive. I think there's a high percentage of compressors that "live like that" for decades possibly.

Comment: Devil, how many compressors in the world? How often is explosion reported?

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic, however, I answered anyway to help alleviate unwarranted fears.

Comment: No I didn't say that there was no risk, I said *AFAIK* the risk of anything dangerous happening is small to non-existent. That's not the same thing at all as saying there's none. Everyone assumes various risks in ww (as much as in aspects of daily life) and makes their own call on risk v reward (+safety precaution/avoidance) themselves, based on what they know & gut feeling. Best example of this in ww is probably the table saw, which a few users consider too dangerous a tool to use. This isn't much different to some refusing to drive on the freeway and only using surface streets [contd]

Comment: Now while I personally consider the risk small enough that I wouldn't give it a second thought, you have to make your own call yourself. Don't be swayed by others' opinions; *the risk is **not** zero*, so there is a judgment to make here. If you want to err on the side of caution err on the side of caution, but make the call after doing the research about what can happen, and most importantly *the frequency*.

Answer (score 3):

#### The question asked:

> Is there danger of corrosion?

**Yes.**

#### The question *not* asked:

> Is there any danger to be worried about from this corrosion?

**No.** <sub>See reasons below</sub>

---

#### The question asked in comments:

> Wouldn't the pressure build up to 150lb and then the corroded tank will explode sending metal shards flying?

**No.**

I've had 3 air compressors sitting in my uninsulated, unheated garage over the last 30 years. The first two were replaced (each after about 15 years - just got the 3rd last summer) due to physical damage and my inability to find replacement parts (and lack of desire/skills to fabricate them).

They were left plugged in *and turned on* for *long* periods of time (like a year at a time) with very little use. This means they would run, sucking in dryish winter air and *very* humid (80+%) Midwest US air, slowly leak pressure (as they're wont to do), then run again to bring the pressure back up.

Once a year or so when I'd remember to drain the tank, I'd haul one outside, blow out some nice brown (rust laden) water, close the drain plug, roll it inside, plug it in, and ignore it for another year or more. No, this is *not* the proper way to care for a compressor.

As noted in a comment, how often do you hear of compressor tanks exploding? Never. I'm sure mine are not the only, nor the worst, abused compressors on the planet and it's just not a problem.

Additional support for the lack of concern comes from the Mythbusters. They [*shot*](https://youtu.be/JowxxVFclUk?t=5574) a scuba tank (pressurized to ***3000*** PSI) with a rifle and the tank didn't explode (watch about 2-3 minutes of the video to see the results of the shot). Therefore, it is *extremely* unlikely that your tank will *explode* due to rusting from the inside out. Granted, the tank, with 3000 PSI rocketed around and you wouldn't want to be in the way. However, a pin-hole puncture at 150 PSI or less probably won't move a 40+lb compressor much, and even if it does, it's still not an explosion.

What is likely to happen is that a *tiny* pinhole leak will *eventually* develop and air will escape. When you run the compressor, air will be used through the hose for your intended purpose, and air will leak out this small hole constantly. Your compressor will cycle more often trying to maintain internal pressure. You'll be annoyed by the more frequent running. You'll be annoyed by the high-pitched sound of air escaping through the pin-hole. You will *not* catch shrapnel from an explosion.

Comment: Exactly what I would have said.

Comment: No is unfortunately overstating it. I didn't want to sidestep the Q as asked and essentially answer a different query like this, because in fact there **is** a chance of explosion. I presume most users don't know this (I sure didn't before seeing [this](https://youtu.be/akAoznYEzts) Gosforth Handyman video) but after I still made the call that the chances of an accident are so small as to be inconsequential, and statistics certainly bear this out. But once you see a photo or two of what can happen (inc. collateral damage) I think a reasonable person would take more care than we typically do!!

Comment: That video, @Graphus, shows that rust can happen inside a compressor. Nobody is denying that. His compressor was **37** years old with an unknown history. He showed that it had been tested to 225PSI with an operating pressure of 150PSI so it's been tested to 150% percent of it's recommended max operating pressure. He measured that after grinding to remove the pits, he'd taken away 21% of the thickness. Let's say that it would have only tested to 89% of the original 225PSI. That still leaves it at 177PSI for a successful test. (cont...)

Comment: That _still_ does _not_ mean it's going to explode at any point! When some area of the tank finally gets thin enough that it can't contain the pressure, it will blow through, but it won't cause the entire tank to disintegrate into shrapnel flying everywhere. There's a _huge_ difference between _leaking_ and _exploding_. If a tank at 300PSI, punctured instantly with a bullet won't explode, then why would a tank at 150PSI (or less) with a slowly developing pin hole explode? There's just no reason to assume it would.

Comment: [Here](https://youtu.be/JowxxVFclUk?t=3402) is the Mythbuster episode where they shoot the tank (cued to the start of the segment), and [here](https://youtu.be/JowxxVFclUk?t=4412) it is cued up to where they actually shoot it (just before to cover a bit of background) watch for about 60 seconds to see what the tank looks like _after_ the shot. Oh, BTW, I had the PSI off a bit. By an order of magnitude. A scuba tank is pressurized to **3000** PSI, not the 300 I remembered. Spoiler alert: The tank does NOT explode

Comment: Sorry, that 2nd link was to a shot at the empty tank, not a pressurized tank. I've added a link to the pressurized tank shot into the answer itself.

Comment: FreeMan, way to completely miss my point ;-) Read my last Comment under the OP. "*That still does not mean it's going to explode at any point!"* But explosions are not a myth! The things we don't know that you're not factoring in inc: the age of the compressor (still relevant for new cos of poss. Chinese quality issues, not just manufacture [the welds] but materials [q.v. terrible cast iron in many modern vices]), the state of the PR valve, whether the tank was EVER tested for pressure and if so to what overpressure. Any one or a combination of things CAN lead to explosion, so no blanket "no".

Comment: And I'm sorry, but the scuba-tank thing is just a Red Herring. There is zero relevance to compressor tanks because they are made in a completely different way, obviously necessary to safety contain the much much higher pressures involved.

Comment: @Graphus If you can provide evidence of compressor tanks exploding, then I will happily retract my answer. Until then, despite cheap junk being exported from the East to all parts of the world, I'll stand by my statement.